# psql coloured prompt misbehaving

Tags: postgresql, psql, client

In theory, there is a possibility to use coloured [prompts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING) in `psql`.  I decided (not the first time :) that I need them, so I thought I would give them a try.  So I have in my `.psqlrc` the following:

```
\set prompt_colour '%[%033[1;33m%]'
\set reset_colour '%[%033[0m%]'

\set PROMPT1 :prompt_colour'%n@%/%R%#%':reset_colour
```

This is very nice, I have a fancy yellow prompt.  Everything is good until I don't start walking back in the command history and hit a long enough command (in my experiments, 37 is OK, 38 is too long and multiline commands of any length do the same) - when I do, the <kbd>Home</kbd> button does not go back to the end of the row, it stops (in this case) 11 characters to the right.  If now I try to edit the command, it gets edited in the wrong positions.

I try to depict this:

```
# SELECT 123456789012345678 FROM a_table;
[here is an error, of course, but it doesn't count]
# SELECT 123456789012345678 FROM a_table;
[ cursor is  ^ here after pressing Home ]
[ hitting Enter gives the error ]
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ELECT"
LINE 1: ELECT 123456789012345678 FROM a_table;
```

(From the documentation it looks like this version should also work but here the control characters aren't parsed, so I have no coloured prompt by the two expressions echoed:

```
\set PROMPT1 "%:prompt_colour:%n@%/%R%#%:reset_colour:"
```

but this results in

```
%[%033[1;33m%]postgres@postgres=#%[%033[0m%]
```

)

So does anybody has any idea how to do this properly?

Somehow I managed to omit the versions so here they are:

- ubuntu 12.10
- psql 9.1.9 (as far as I know, it is installed from a standard ubuntu package)
- both libreadline5 and 6 are installed, also libedit2

### My findings:

Following Peter's advice, I tried modifying the `pg_wrapper` script to link against `libreadline.so.6` - in itself it works but the error is still there.  The same with `libreadline.so.5` (which is the default one, I think).  With `libeditline.so.0` the situation is much worse.

Comment: If Windows, also see http://superuser.com/q/961711/78897

Answer (score 3):

I have experience this exact same thing in the past.  It usually happens because you have linked psql against an inferior readline-like library.  If you are using libedit, use libreadline instead.  If you are using libreadline, use a different one.  Details depend on your operating system and method of installation.

Comment: I have included the versions and findings, could you please check them?